# SQL - How to transpose results from SUM CASE expression with THEN 1 THEN 0

Tags: sql

I have data that I am recategorizing with SUM(CASE WHEN...) and calculating counts for each category:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '0' AND '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "0-11", 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '12' AND '17' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "12-17",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '18' AND '24' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "18-24",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '25' AND '64' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "25-64",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age >= '65' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "65+"
   FROM Table1
```

This gives me:

| 0-11 | 12-17 | 18-24 | 25-64 | 65+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 8 | 11 | 17 | 22 |

How do I rewrite my code so it will instead give me the results transposed?

| Age | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0-11 | 10 |
| 12-17 | 8 |
| 18-24 | 11 |
| 25-64 | 17 |
| 65+ | 22 |

I tried using pivot but got stuck with what to put as "columnname"

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '0' AND '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "0-11", 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '12' AND '17' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "12-17",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '18' AND '24' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "18-24",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '25' AND '64' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "25-64",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age >= '65' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "65+"
   FROM Table1
pivot
    (
        max(value)
        FOR columnname IN ("0-11", "12-17", "18-24", "25-64", "65+")
    )
```

Comment: If age is integer do not compare it to character strings.  If age is character format, then you have a bigger problem because '9' doesn't fall between '0' and '11'

Comment: Here is a fiddle to help us collaborate on the problem https://dbfiddle.uk/wmBsYW0N

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Case When Age <= 11 Then '00-11'
            When Age <= 17 Then '12-17'
            When Age <= 24 Then '18-24'
            When Age <= 64 Then '25-64'
            Else '65+'
       End as age_range, count(*) as Number
From Table1
Group By 1
Order By 1
```

Comment: [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mgS1Xqpm)

Comment: @xQbert, the "between"s  in your demo are unnecessary.  When you get past the first Case test (<=11) you already know age is at least 12, so <=17 gets you the 12-17 group without a second test.

Answer (score 1):

You could flip this a little on its head and use a table of ranges which you can join to; this has the advantage it's very easy to change or add new ranges without needing to edit the actual query.

```
select a.Age, Count(*) Count
from (
  values('0-11', 0, 11),('12-17', 12, 17),('18-24', 18, 24),('25-64', 25, 64),('65+', 65, 99)
)a(Age, vmin, vmax)
left join (
  select Age
  from t
)t on t.Age >= a.vmin and t.Age <= a.vmax
group by a.Age
```

Example [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TGbHDAXZ)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 
(
    AGE INT
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (AGE) VALUES
    ('0'),  ('1'),  ('2'),  ('3'),  ('4'),  ('5'),  ('6'),  ('7'),  ('8'),
    ('9'),  ('12'), ('13'), ('14'), ('15'), ('16'), ('17'), ('17'), ('17'),
    ('18'), ('18'), ('19'), ('19'), ('20'), ('20'), ('21'), ('21'), ('22'),
    ('22'), ('24'), ('25'), ('25'),('25'),  ('26'), ('26'), ('26'), ('27'),
    ('27'), ('27'), ('28'), ('28'), ('28'), ('30'), ('40'), ('50'), ('60'),
    ('64'), ('65'), ('65'), ('65'), ('65'), ('65'), ('65'), ('66'), ('66'), 
    ('66'), ('66'), ('67'), ('67'), ('67'), ('68'), ('68'), ('68'),('69'),  
    ('69'), ('69'), ('69'), ('70'), ('71');

--Verify the contents of Table1
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '0' AND '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "0-11", 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '12' AND '17' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "12-17",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '18' AND '24' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "18-24",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '25' AND '64' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "25-64",
       SUM(CASE WHEN Age >= '65' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "65+"
   FROM Table1

--Display age group totals in rows  
SELECT Age, total as [Count]
FROM
(
  SELECT 1 as seq, SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '0' AND '11' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as total, '0-11' Age
  FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 as seq,SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '12' AND '17' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as total, '12-17' Age
  FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 as seq,SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '18' AND '24' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as total, '18-24' Age
  FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 as seq,SUM(CASE WHEN Age BETWEEN '25' AND '64' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as total, '25-64' Age
  FROM Table1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 as seq,SUM(CASE WHEN Age >= '65' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as total, '65+' Age
  FROM Table1  
) src
GROUP BY Age, total,seq
ORDER BY seq
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DVT-2U3s)

| Age | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0-11 | 10 |
| 12-17 | 8 |
| 18-24 | 11 |
| 25-64 | 17 |
| 65+ | 22 |

Answer (score 0):

Example with range table. Create table like this:

```
create table age_range (id int,rangeDescr varchar(20),start_age int,end_age int);
insert into age_range values
 (1,'0-11',0,11)
,(2,'12-17',12,17)
,(3,'18-24',18,24)  
,(4,'25-64',25,64)  
,(5,'65+',65,1000)
;
```

Perhaps you already have such a table. It can also be changed without changing the query for the report.

Then

```
select rangeDescr,count(*) qty
from age_range r
left join table1 t on t.age between r.start_age and r.end_age
group by rangeDescr
```

[Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/74DMNrWJ)